# Package listings doesn't work

Tags: listings

I'm trying to understand how to use `listings`.

In the preamble I have:

```
\usepackage {listings}
```

Inside my document I wrote:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ nothing !}
end;
write(’Welcome !’);
\end{lstlisting}
```

It all doesn't work. I'm wondering why.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{ia_urb_thesis} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\titolo{xxxxxx... \[5mm] } 
\candidato{io} 
\relatore{Chiar.mo Prof.~A} 
\annoaccademico{2011-2012} 
\copertinatesi \dedica{Ai miei genitori} 
\indice \indicefigure \indicetabelle \iniziatesto 
\include{cap_1} 
\include{cap_2} 
\appendix 
\include{app_a} 
\include{biblio} 
\ringraziamenti Vorrei ringraziare ... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What do you mean precisely by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: it means that it doesn't show the code ..I use Winedt.

Comment: Further to egreg's comment, could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) :)

Comment: Please, show a complete, but minimal, example of code, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @g9999 You can edit your question to add code, better than doing it within a comment.

Comment: @g9999 : This MWE is neither minimal (many non included external files) nor working (no `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @Brent.Longborough `latin9` has the Euro symbol, for instance.

Comment: @egreg Oh, yes. Of course it's a personal choice, but I myself wouldn't bother -- I'd just go straight to `utf-8`

Comment: I changed latin1 to latin9...but nothing has changed. I use Winedt and it's configured to use UTF-8..I also have another problem with line breaks..After I use ttfamily I'm unable to set a line break..thanks

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following MWE (in this form it is compilable without errors):

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85260/package-listings-doesnt-work
\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage {listings}

%configurating listings:
\lstset{language=Pascal,             % Language in Listing
  basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,   % generall style for listing
  commentstyle=\ttfamily,            % type writer font for comments
  stringstyle=\rmfamily,             % normal font for strings
  showstringspaces=true,             % shows blanks in strings
  breaklines=true,                   % allows breaking of lines
  frameround=ffff,                   % see manual
  frame=lines,                       % see manual
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},    % just to show
} 

\begin{document}
Inside my document I wrote:
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ nothing !}
end;
write('Welcome !');
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I corrected the line with the welcome as mentioned in my comment to get a runable MWE. I also deleted all not nececcary for a MWE to give you a start point. Perhaps your thesis package causes errors ...

**Update:**
I added a part (see macro `lstset`) to configure `listings`. Have please a look on the comments I inserted in the MWE. With `texdoc listings` on the command line you can read the manual (very useful :-). You can use predefined languages (here Pascal), you can define the used fonts for the complete listings (here `\ttfamily`) and so on. To configure your listing please have a look into the manual.

Comment: I believe that g9999 is worried about the "normal" appearance of the listing. Perhaps you can add some example for customizing it, for instance to set a language or to change the font.

Answer (score 3):

I found an external link to [`ia_urb_thesis`](http://code.google.com/p/applied-cs-graduation-projects/source/browse/trunk/FObject/Tesi/ia_urb_thesis.sty?r=369). It is a google code project.

It seems there are a lot of things wrong/missing in your example.

Firstly, there is no `\begin{document}` in your example.

Secondly,

```
\titolo{<>} 
\candidato{<>} 
\relatore{<>} 
\annoaccademico{<>} 
\copertinatesi 
\dedica{<>} 
\indice 
\indicefigure 
\indicetabelle 
\iniziatesto
```

must go after `\begin{document}`.

Thirdly, the `\[` in `\titolo{xxxxxx... \[5mm] }` puts the succeeding code into math environment. You can change it into `\\[5mm]` for vertical spacing but I doubt that it will do you any good. You should just write `\titolo{xxxxxx...}` as it is.

The character `’` throws errors around but if you replace it with `'` it works fine even with `latin1` input. I don't know what you use that encoding for. But generally, you can get by with `utf8`.

Here is the code. You can use the modification in the other answer of the `lstlistings` environment or use your own fancier one.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{ia_urb_thesis} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Pascal}
\begin{document}
\titolo{xxxxxx} 
\candidato{io} 
\relatore{Chiar.mo Prof.~A} 
\annoaccademico{2011-2012} 
\copertinatesi \dedica{Ai miei genitori} 
\indice \indicefigure \indicetabelle \iniziatesto 
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ nothing !}
end;
write(`Welcome !');
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]